# no such variable in pltcl trigger when using Django, audit tables

Tags: django, postgresql, triggers, tcl

I have an audit implementation via pltcl triggers in a postgresql database in a Django application, I want to track every data change on tables, and django-audit-log is not enough because we need to track changes via sql directly too, in psql I can insert, update, delete, and everything goes good, but in Django when the app is running with the same database user, the following error is thrown:

```
DatabaseError at /recolecta/nuevo
can't read "tgname_act": no such variable
CONTEXT:  can't read "tgname_act": no such variable
    while executing
"spi_exec "SELECT a.attname AS pk_name
          FROM pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_index i
          WHERE c.relname = '$tgname_act' AND c.oid = i.in..."
    (procedure "__PLTcl_proc_71035_trigger" line 23)
    invoked from within
"__PLTcl_proc_71035_trigger tgrt_informationgathering_restitutionrequeststate 53594 informationgathering_restitutionrequeststate public {{} id restitut..."
in PL/Tcl function "rtaudit_function"
Request Method: POST
Request URL:  http://192.168.1.108:8001/recolecta/nuevo
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:  
can't read "tgname_act": no such variable
CONTEXT:  can't read "tgname_act": no such variable
    while executing
"spi_exec "SELECT a.attname AS pk_name
          FROM pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_index i
          WHERE c.relname = '$tgname_act' AND c.oid = i.in..."
    (procedure "__PLTcl_proc_71035_trigger" line 23)
    invoked from within
"__PLTcl_proc_71035_trigger tgrt_informationgathering_restitutionrequeststate 53594 informationgathering_restitutionrequeststate public {{} id restitut..."
in PL/Tcl function "rtaudit_function"
Exception Location: /home/igor/.virtualenvs/registrotierras_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in execute, line 44
Python Executable:  /home/igor/.virtualenvs/registrotierras_app/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
```

the definition of the trigger is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rtaudit_function() RETURNS "trigger" AS
$BODY$
set i 0
set thecounter 1
set pk_name ""
set pk_value ""
set theuser "registrotierras"

# user
spi_exec "SELECT CURRENT_USER AS tguser"
# tablename | table_rtaudit
spi_exec "SELECT relname AS tgname, relname || '_rtaudit' AS tgname_act FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = $TG_relid"
spi_exec "SELECT a.attname AS pk_name
          FROM pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_index i
          WHERE c.relname = '$tgname_act' AND c.oid = i.indrelid AND a.attnum > 0 AND a.attrelid = i.indexrelid AND i.indisprimary='t'"


# Make sure the audit table exists, if not, we create it
spi_exec "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cols FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = '$tgname_act' AND table_schema = 'rtaudit'"
if {$cols == 0} {
  spi_exec "CREATE TABLE rtaudit.$tgname_act AS SELECT text('1') AS theuser_rtaudit, current_timestamp AS thetime_rtaudit, text('I') AS theactivity_rtaudit, * FROM $tgname WHERE 1 = 0"
  spi_exec "GRANT ALL ON rtaudit.$tgname_act TO $theuser"
}

set uni [concat "INSERT INTO rtaudit.$tgname_act" "(theuser_rtaudit, thetime_rtaudit, theactivity_rtaudit, "]
set uni1 ""

switch $TG_op {
  INSERT {
    foreach field $TG_relatts {
      if {[string equal -nocase [lindex [array get NEW $field] 0] $pk_name] == 0} {
        incr i
      }
    }

    foreach field $TG_relatts {
      if {[string equal -nocase [lindex [array get NEW $field] 0] $pk_name] == 0} {
        if {$thecounter < $i} {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$field,"]
        } else {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$field"]
        }
        incr thecounter
      }
    }
    set uni [concat "$uni" ") VALUES ('$tguser', now(), '$TG_op', "]
    set thecounter 1;

    foreach field $TG_relatts {
      if {[string equal -nocase [lindex [array get NEW $field] 0] $pk_name] == 0} {
        set current_value [quote [lindex [array get NEW $field] 1]]
        if {$current_value == ""} {
          set current_value "NULL"
        } else {
          set current_value "'$current_value'"
        }

        if {$thecounter < $i} {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$current_value,"]
        } else {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$current_value"]
        }
        incr thecounter
      }
    }

    set uni [concat "$uni" ")"]
  }
  UPDATE {
    set thesize [llength $TG_relatts]
    set thesize [expr $thesize - 1]

    for {set i 1} {$i <= $thesize} {incr i} {
      set field [lindex $TG_relatts $i]
      if {$i < $thesize} {
        set uni [concat "$uni" "$field,"]
      } else {
        set uni [concat "$uni" "$field"]
      }
    }
    set uni1 $uni
    set uni [concat "$uni" ") VALUES ('$tguser', now(), '$TG_op', "]
    set uni1 [concat "$uni1" ") VALUES ('$tguser', now(), 'PREVIOUS', "]

    for {set i 1} {$i <= $thesize} {incr i} {
      set field [lindex $TG_relatts $i]
      set current_value [quote [lindex [array get NEW $field] 1]]

      if {$current_value == ""} {
        set current_value "NULL"
      } else {
        set current_value "'$current_value'"
      }

      if {$i < $thesize} {
        set uni [concat "$uni" "$current_value,"]
      } else {
        set uni [concat "$uni" "$current_value"]
      }
    }

    for {set i 1} {$i <= $thesize} {incr i} {
      set field [lindex $TG_relatts $i]
      set previous_value [quote [lindex [array get OLD $field] 1]]

      if {$previous_value == ""} {
        set previous_value "NULL"
      } else {
        set previous_value "'$previous_value'"
      }

      if {$i < $thesize} {
        set uni1 [concat "$uni1" "$previous_value,"]
      } else {
        set uni1 [concat "$uni1" "$previous_value"]
      }
    }

    set uni [concat "$uni" ")"]
    set uni1 [concat "$uni1" ")"]
  }
  DELETE {
    foreach field $TG_relatts {
      if {[string equal -nocase [lindex [array get OLD $field] 0] $pk_name] == 0} {
        incr i
      }
    }

    foreach field $TG_relatts {
      if {[string equal -nocase [lindex [array get OLD $field] 0] $pk_name] == 0} {
        if {$thecounter < $i} {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$field,"]
        } else {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$field"]
        }
        incr thecounter
      }
    }
    set uni [concat "$uni" ") VALUES ('$tguser', now(), '$TG_op', "]
    set thecounter 1;

    foreach field $TG_relatts {
      if {[string equal -nocase [lindex [array get OLD $field] 0] $pk_name] == 0} {
        set current_value [quote [lindex [array get OLD $field] 1]]

        if {$current_value == ""} {
          set current_value "NULL"
        } else {
          set current_value "'$current_value'"
        }

        if {$thecounter < $i} {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$current_value,"]
        } else {
          set uni [concat "$uni" "$current_value"]
        }
        incr thecounter
      }
    }
    set uni [concat "$uni" ")"]
  }
}

# Execute the query y error management
if {[catch {spi_exec $uni} catchres]} {
        set uni2 "INSERT INTO error_rtaudit (thetime, thetable, error, query) VALUES (NOW(), '$tgname_act', '$catchres', '$uni')"
        if {[catch {spi_exec $uni2} catchres1]} {
                set uni3 "INSERT INTO error_rtaudit (thetime, error) VALUES (NOW(), '$catchres')"
                if {[catch {spi_exec $uni3} catchres]} {
                        set errormsg "ERROR 1"
                }
        } else {
                set errormsg "ERROR 2"
        }
} else {
        set errormsg "OK"
}

set thesize [string length $uni1]
if { $thesize > 0 } {
        if {[catch {spi_exec $uni1} catchres]} {
                set uni2 "INSERT INTO error_rtaudit (thetime, thetable, error, query) VALUES (NOW(), '$tgname_act', '$catchres', '$uni1')"
                if {[catch {spi_exec $uni2} catchres1]} {
                        set uni3 "INSERT INTO error_rtaudit (thetime, error) VALUES (NOW(), '$catchres')"
                        if {[catch {spi_exec $uni3} catchres]} {
                                set errormsg [concat "$errormsg" " | ERROR 1"]
                        }
                } else {
                        set errormsg [concat "$errormsg" " | ERROR 2"]
                }
        } else {
                set errormsg [concat "$errormsg" " | OK"]
        }
}

return OK
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'pltcl' VOLATILE;
```

What is necessary to be done in Django in order to make it work? or would it be necessary to avoid pltcl?  The postgresql Database is 9.1 on an Ubuntu Server, but I guess it's more related to Django and some permission in postgresql

Comment: The error points to the trigger, the variable tgname_act seems to be not defined anywhere and isn't part of the signature of the function. I do not know the scoping rules of pgtcl, but if there isn't some magic its simply undefined.
You could define it with a simple `set tgname_act "something"`but thats probably not the correct fix.

Comment: I changed the lines to make sure I intercepted in an array the spi_exec results but again pltcl complained, but just called when called via Django view like so : `spi_exec -array C "SELECT relname AS tgname, relname || '_rtaudit' AS tgname_act FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = $TG_relid"
set tgname_act $C(tgname_act)
set tgname $C(tgname)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this query does not find anything:

```
spi_exec "SELECT relname AS tgname, relname || '_rtaudit' AS tgname_act
          FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = $TG_relid"
```

Anyway this leads to the fact that `tgname_act` is not defined.
You can check if the variable exist with `info exists tgname_act` and provide a useful default value.

Example:

```
spi_exec "SELECT relname AS tgname, relname || '_rtaudit' AS tgname_act
          FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = $TG_relid"
if {![info exists tgname_act]} {set tgname_act "foo_rtaudit"}
```

If you don't do such checks with in PL/Tcl, then your trigger will at some time blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about your own code, my suggestion is use tablelog: http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/

It is what we do in LedgerSMB for auditing certain tables.

Your current problem though is probably that instead of tgname_act, you probably mean either TG_name or TG_table_name.